# Cygwin Curl 'failed writing body' error when using clipboard

Tags: curl, cygwin

Out of the blue this problem started happening.

Something like

```
curl www.cnn.com > /dev/clipboard
```

results in

```
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
```

Error 23 apparently means there is something wrong with the file or file system. I'm able to export to a txt file, it's just the clipboard. I've been using this for a long time with no issues. I tried re-installing Cygwin but no go.

Only thing I can think of is that I recently added the MySQL package to Cygwin, but I can't see how that would impact anything.

This is a Curl error not a Cygwin error as clipboard works for trivial commands such as

```
echo 'hello' > /dev/clipboard
```

Nor does it appear to be a fork issue because the following command also works:

```
curl www.cnn.com > cnn.txt
```

I'm really at a loss on this one

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I reported this as a bug http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-12/msg00198.html - which is fixed in a snapshot and should be taken care of in the next release (after 2013-12-09).  In the mean-time you can:

Install `cygutils-extra` and use `putclip.exe` to put the contents into the clipboard.  I too am experiencing problems writing to `/dev/clipboard` on my win8.1 machine (see below).

```
$ curl www.cnn.com > /dev/clipboard
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 65371    0 65371    0     0   139k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  141k
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1460)
```

but using putclip works:

```
$ curl www.cnn.com |putclip.exe 
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  120k    0  120k    0     0   178k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  189k
```

---

I just started having /dev/clipboard problems:
This works:

```
$ echo "test" > /dev/clipboard
```

now try from a file:

```
$ echo test > /tmp/t
$ cat /tmp/t
test
$ cat /tmp/t > /dev/clipboard
cat: write error: Permission denied
```

but putclip works:

```
$ echo "test" >/tmp/t
$ cat /tmp/t |putclip.exe 
$ getclip.exe 
test
```

Weird, huh? Not sure when this cropped up. I was able to redirect to /dev/clipboard until recently.

Here is a "cb" function.  If 0 is open it calls getclip, otherwise it calls putclip:

```
cb() { test -t 0 && getclip || putclip ; }
```

Test:

```
$ echo test2 | cb
$ cb
test2
```

so just pipe to the `cb` function, if that makes it easier.

Comment: sent in a bug report to cygwin: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-12/msg00198.html